# ASP.NET Masterpages reloading each time

Tags: asp.net

I am using masterpages in my aspnet website. .
Whenever I refresh or reload or redirect to another page of same application , the complete page is getting reloaded which taking lot of time in binding header and footers. ....

Is there any other way keep header and footer constant and only content inside it get reloaded........

Comment: That is exactly what a master page does. It carries everything inside her to the content pages.

Answer (score 3):

That is not something MasterPages is going to solve for you.

[MasterPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are intended to easily reuse the framework of your site.

Picture from MSDN explaining the behavior of MasterPages:

[image]

As you see, it's just A+B.

If you want to prevent reloading it every time, use AJAX.

Comment: using AJAX is the best option... i wil try

Comment: @PrakashN: if you need more help, just let me know. Also, please don't forget to mark your question answered if you question is answered for you.